# How to Know If in the Last Repeat of Repeat Keyword

Tags: robotframework

The [Repeat Keyword](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Repeat%20Keyword) Robot Framework command allows you to keep running a keyword for a certain number of cycles or a certain amount of time. I want to have one type of Teardown for all intermediate Repeats but a final other teardown at the end of the test. Is there an internal variable or something else under the hood that I can check to see if the last Repeat is being run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly doubt it.

But there's a workaround. Just make a regular for loop with index and use `Run Keyword` there. Then do then conditional calls based on the index.

Comment: It would be nice if this applied to time-based Repeat Keyword too, but I'll have to deal with it.